python - track Solana transfers between two wallets
Using python (beginner) I'm trying to read in two text files - each text file has a list of wallets on the Solana network.
Wanting to test if any wallets in the first text file have transferred SOL or SPL Tokens to any wallets in the second text file and if not, display a message stating so.
This is what I have so far:
import requests

def read_wallet_addresses(file_path):
    """Read wallet addresses from a file."""
    print(f"Reading wallet addresses from: {file_path}")
    with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
        addresses = [line.strip() for line in file.readlines()]
    print(f"Successfully read {len(addresses)} addresses from {file_path}.")
    return addresses

def check_transaction_involvement(transaction_signature, wallet_a, wallet_b):
    """Check if a given transaction involves an SPL Token or SOL Transfer between two wallets."""
    print(f"Checking involvement in transaction: {transaction_signature} between {wallet_a} and {wallet_b}")
    url = "https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com"
    headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
    payload = {
        "jsonrpc": "2.0",
        "id": 1,
        "method": "getTransaction",
        "params": [
            transaction_signature,
            "jsonParsed"
        ]
    }
    
    response = requests.post(url, json=payload, headers=headers)
    print(f"Transaction check response status code: {response.status_code}")
    if response.status_code == 200:
        data = response.json()
        print(f"Transaction data: {data}")  # For debugging
        if 'result' in data and 'transaction' in data['result']:
            transaction_info = data['result']['transaction']
            # Simplified involvement check for debugging purposes
            return True  # Assume involvement for debugging
    return False

def find_transactions(wallet_list_a, wallet_list_b):
    """Find transactions between wallets in two lists."""
    print("Starting to find transactions...")
    found_transactions = []
    
    for wallet_a in wallet_list_a:
        print(f"\nChecking transactions for wallet: {wallet_a}")
        url = "https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com"
        headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
        payload = {
            "jsonrpc": "2.0",
            "id": 1,
            "method": "getSignaturesForAddress",
            "params": [
                wallet_a,
                {
                    "limit": 100,  # Increased limit for broader transaction history
                }
            ]
        }
        
        response = requests.post(url, json=payload, headers=headers)
        print(f"API call status for wallet {wallet_a}: {response.status_code}")
        if response.status_code == 200:
            data = response.json()
            print(f"Found {len(data.get('result', []))} transactions for wallet {wallet_a}.")  # Debugging
            for transaction in data.get('result', []):
                transaction_signature = transaction['signature']
                for wallet_b in wallet_list_b:
                    # Simplified check for debugging
                    if check_transaction_involvement(transaction_signature, wallet_a, wallet_b):
                        print(f"Transaction between {wallet_a} and {wallet_b} found: {transaction_signature}")
                        found_transactions.append((wallet_a, wallet_b, transaction_signature))
                        break  # Found a matching transaction, no need to check the rest of wallet_b
    
    return found_transactions

# Incorporating the provided file paths
wallet_list_a = read_wallet_addresses('wallets_a.txt')
wallet_list_b = read_wallet_addresses('wallets_b.txt')

transactions = find_transactions(wallet_list_a, wallet_list_b)

if transactions:
    print("\nFound transactions:")
    for wallet_a, wallet_b, transaction_id in transactions:
        print(f"Transaction ID: {transaction_id} between wallets {wallet_a} and {wallet_b}")
else:
    print("\nNo transactions found between the lists of wallets.")


I left out the file paths for wallets_a and wallets_b but they were just text files on my desktop. So far this is all i'm getting in return:
Checking transactions for wallet: (listed here is the wallet from wallets_a.txt)
No transactions found between the lists of wallets.
Can anybody get this working? Thanks for taking a look. It doesn't seem to be connecting to the blockchain and getting the data needed. Any insight would be helpful.

Your code works for me... it does return a bunch of 429s since it's making the requests directly without respecting any backoff requests. Be sure that the addresses are encoded in base58, and it should work perfectly!
